# How can I reduce the output from VS2010 project builds?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

VS2010, 100+ projects in solution.

I'm tired of seeing the 115+ lines of the "Project Performance Summary", "Target Performance Summary", and "Task Performance Summary" sections after each project is built.  It shows up in the Output window -and- in the log file.  There is nothing useful (to me) in those lines (usually) and they just clutter the output.  VS2005 and VS2008 didn't output all of that extra stuff.

But I don't see any way to turn that noise off.  The two Tools->Options->ProjectsAndSolutions->BuildAndRun "verbosity" settings don't affect that at all.

How can I prevent that part of the build output?

Comment: Mysterious problem, those are exactly the settings you use to limit the noise.  Document exactly *what* you changed better.

Comment: I changed each of those two "verbosity" settings (individually, then together) from the (apparent default) "Minimal" to "Quiet". No effect on -that- output. Those did reduce the specific compiler/linker output, but did not remove those " * Performance Summary" sections. Other values for those settings appear to INCREASE the output.  Has anyone managed to get rid of those " * Peformance Summary" sections when building C++ via the IDE? These are Windows .libs/.dlls/.exes being built.

Comment: There have been some reports of the VS2010 upgrade from an earlier version not going smoothly.  It tries to preserve the config changes.  The big hammer is Tools + Import/Export + Reset.  Save it first if you care about your customizations.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try.    By "customizations", do you mean changes to settings that affect VS for every "solution" it works on? I don't think I've changed much of that stuff, other than the tab settings in the editor.

Comment: Yes, tab settings.  Key bindings, toolbars, colors, fonts, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Oops.  I wasn't logged in when I posted or when I answered.  And no my browser has lost the cookie or whatever that let it remember me.  Otherwise, I would have editted the answer above.  (Seems I'm doing everything wrong here.)

I wanted to post the solution to the above problem.  Hans was correct that the installation of VS2010 on a system that already had VS2005 and/or VS2008 tried to maintain the config from the older version.  One part of the older config was this setting:
      Tools->
        Options->
          Projects And Solutions->
            VC++ Project Settings->
              Build Timing

That was set to "Yes" in my VS2005/VS2008 installations, but it seems to do nothing or very little to the build output in those versions.

In VS2010, it turns on those "Performance Summary" sections in the output.  In addition, that setting overrides the two verbosity settings mentioned earlier, so those sections appear even if the verbosity settings are at "Quiet".

I changed the "Build Timing" setting to "No", and now I only see those sections if the verbosity settings are at "Diagnostic".  I think that's the way it was intended to work.

So, that's the solution: Force the "Build Timing" setting to "No" and the "Performance Summary" sections go away (unless you use the verbosity settings to turn them on).

Comment: Ah.  Wasn't a cookie problem. I was just on the wrong browser when I posted the actual solution above.  Silly mistake.

Comment: Yes but then you loose the time it took to build. I'm not sure why the endless number of counters are necessary. Good question though, I wish I could get rid of these and keep the build time.

Comment: You mean the time on the "rebuild" line in the Project Performance Summary?  With BuildTiming turned off, I still get the build time displayed as the last line for each project:   eg,  "11>Time Elapsed 00:00:40.56".

Answer (score 3):

[[ I'm only answering my own question because the solution was provided in comments to the original question above, and I don't see any way to mark it "Answered" without an Answer being posted. ]]

The Tools -> ImportAndExport -> Reset that Hans Passant suggested in the comments above worked.

As he warned, I exported my settings first, so I can now export the Reset settings and compare the two sets to see what change actually caused the weird build output. Then I'll restore my saved settings with that (hopefully) ONE change. If that works, I can tell everyone on my team how to fix this silly problem that's been plaguing us.

I'll post that detail here, also.

Now that I can see the correct build output, it appears that the output I reported was a strange mix of "Minimal" and "Diagnostic".  With those "Performance Summary" sections gone, I'll probably go with "Normal" build output.  I have no clue why EVERYONE on our team ended up with that problem.

Thanks go to Hans!  :)

Comment: I hope that marking this as the Accepted Answer doesn't give me some undeserved points or something....

Comment: It doesn't.  It just marks this question as answered on the question list, drawing less attention to it, and keeps your acceptance percentage up, showing that you follow up on questions you ask.

Comment: This solution really helped me gtt rid of all the useless messages in the Build window. For `VS2012` it is `Reset All Settings` then go on `Next Next..untill you fetch Finish`. You are Done.